# C# WPF: add item taking time

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, directoryservices

I am trying to add security groups from a server to combobox in background worker.
But it is taking time and in spite of having background worker UI becomes unresponsive.

```
 private void Accounts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

if (servername.Text == "")
    MessageBox.Show("please enter server");

else
{
    mycombobox.Items.Clear();
    server1 = servername.Text;
    bgw_account = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw_account.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgw_account.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_account_ProgressChanged);


    bgw_account.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_account_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bgw_account.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_account_DoWork);
    bgw_account.RunWorkerAsync();
  }

}


      private void bgw_account_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

      ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();

      po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
      acclist = new List<string>();
      using(PrincipalContext pt= new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine,server1.ToString()))
      using (GroupPrincipal ab = new GroupPrincipal(pt))
      using (var searcher=new PrincipalSearcher(ab))
      using (var results=searcher.FindAll())
       {

        Parallel.ForEach(results,po,(currentsam)=>
        {
        acclist.Add(currentsam.SamAccountName.ToString());//timeconsuming task
        });


       }


  }

       private void bgw_account_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {

        mycombobox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
       {

         mycombobox.Items.Clear();
        }));

           foreach (string p in acclist)
          {
           mycombobox.Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action (()=>
            {
             mycombobox.Items.Add(p);
             }));
          }


        acclist.Clear();
      }
```

Is there any way to improve performance?

Comment: how many results are you getting back? i.e. what is the count of results?

Comment: Around 30 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not tested.**

What `insPrincipalSearcher.FindAll()` do is probably creating a collection without actually searching the AD. The actual AD traffic is done when you loop the `results`.

So please try looping the `results` inside `bgw_account_DoWork` and put the resulting samAccountNames in a list for consumption in `bgw_account_RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems 'insPrincipalSearcher.Findall()'  is building collection within forloop. Changed the code to get this inside

Comment: Now it is taking time around 2 minutes for adding groups in `acclist` inside `bgw_account` , adding combobox in 'bgw_account_RunWorkerCompleted` is not adding delay.

Comment: I don't know how much time it takes before the change. So 2 minutes is better or worse? One point to note, moving code into `DoWork` will not speed up the loading time but just solve the UI freeze problem (during the 2 min UI is responsive). To improve the user exp further u may add the any items loaded to UI in `ProgressChanged`. So the UI appear more responsive.